# Configure a Custom Domain Name Using Namecheap and Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, dns

So I have web app on azure  and I want to change domain name. I am using "Namecheap" dns hosting service.

I was following this [tutorial](http://www.yaringarcia.com/post/how-to-configure-a-custom-domain-name-using-namecheap-and-microsoft-azure) to achieve my goal, I have done all steps in tutorial except 6.c (bcs I can't find subdomain settings in new namecheap control panel). Anyway, I was able to complete step 9, but now I have an error when I visit my [site](http://www.w2dance.com):

"Error 404 - Web app not found."

When I am trying to do again step 9 in [tutorial](http://www.yaringarcia.com/post/how-to-configure-a-custom-domain-name-using-namecheap-and-microsoft-azure) there is an error: 
"The host name www.w2dance.com has already been assigned to another site Azure: wheretodance.".

And I don't know what else to do now. Here is my dns settings:
[image]

Here is azure portal screenshot:

[image]

**Update**

After a few hours it start working, so looks like I have panic attack :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DNS settings in NameCheap 's "Advanced DNS" page is not correct. The step 6-C is an important step, because those subdomains are required for Azure Web Apps to verify that you're the owner of w2dance.com domain.

I just modified one of my own domain in my NameCheap account and took a 
**[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a29VH.jpg)**
for you to see the records you should enter for your domain.

I'm also putting the shortened "Host" column values below so you can see the whole texts :

In my 3rd line, "Host" column value is : 
"awverify.www.w2dance.com"

In my 4th line, "Host" column value is : 
"awverify.w2dance.com"

Adding subdomain means adding a CNAME record for your domain. After adding those "awverify." subdomain records, Microsoft Azure Web Apps would be able to verify that you're the owner of w2dance.com because only you can add those "test" subdomains to your domain in your DNS server.

Could you please add those 2 CNAME records and let me know if it will be resolved or not ? Appreciate if you can set as answer if my explanation resolved your issue

Comment: Thx for the answer, but looks like I did all good and after 4 hours it start to work even without subdomain settings . Anyway I suppose your answer it is correct too and may help some1 else.